# Select Option not working but input text is

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js, html-select

I have an endpoint, let say https://localhost:3003/requests
And I have this React form:
First, the input text (this is no problem, I can post data correctly to backend):

```
<div className="input-type">
<input type="text" onChange={setFormData} name="nama"
    className="border w-full px-5 py-3 focus:outline-none rounded-md"
    placeholder="Nama" />

</div>
```

And then, I have this select option that can't post the data:

```
<div className="input-type">
                <label htmlFor="pet” className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    Sektor
                </label>
                <select
                    id="pet”
                    name="pet”
                    autoComplete="pet-name"
                    className="border w-full px-5 py-3 focus:outline-none rounded-md"
                    onChange={setFormData}
                    >
                    <option value="Chika”>Chika</option>
                    <option value="Chiki”>Chiki</option>
                    <option value="Chikoo”>Chikoo</option>

                </select>
            </div>
```

And this is setFormData get from:

```
import { BiPlus } from 'react-icons/bi'
import Success from "./successRequest"
import Bug from "./bugRequest"
import { useQueryClient, useMutation } from "react-query"
import { addRequest, getRequests } from "../../lib/helper"


export default function AddRequestForm({ formData, setFormData }) {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient()
    const addMutation = useMutation(addRequest, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.prefetchQuery('requests', getRequests)
        }
    })

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (Object.keys(formData).length == 0) return console.log("Don't have Form Data");
        let { name, pet } = formData;

        const model = {
            name, pet
        }

        addMutation.mutate(model)
    }

    if (addMutation.isLoading) return <div>Loading!</div>
    if (addMutation.isError) return <Bug message={addMutation.error.message}></Bug>
    if (addMutation.isSuccess) return <Success message={"Added Successfully"}></Success>

return(
<div className="input-type">
<input type="text" onChange={setFormData} name="nama"
    className="border w-full px-5 py-3 focus:outline-none rounded-md"
    placeholder="Nama" />

</div> 

<div className="input-type">
                <label htmlFor="pet” className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    My Pet
                </label>
                <select
                    id="pet”
                    name="pet”
                    autoComplete="pet-name"
                    className="border w-full px-5 py-3 focus:outline-none rounded-md"
                    onChange={setFormData}
                    >
                    <option value="Chika”>Chika</option>
                    <option value="Chiki”>Chiki</option>
                    <option value="Chikoo”>Chikoo</option>

                </select>
            </div>

)}
```

How to do it correctly, so I can pass all input data to backend?

Comment: Can you share the code of setFormData?

Comment: already updated

Comment: Can you share code of the setFormData prop?

Comment: I’m not sure understand what you mean. did you mean addRequest function from lib/helper.js?